# Preserving relative ordering of merge key and explicit keys with ruamel

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm hoping to use ruamel.yaml to perform some automatic edits against a large human-edited YAML file.

The input file contains merge keys, like so:

```
foo: &foo
  color: red

bar:
  name: qux
  <<: *foo
```

If possible, I'd like to preserve the relative ordering of the explicit `name` key and the `<<` merge key, but it looks like ruamel really wants the merge key to come first. Here's what I get when I round-trip this YAML through ruamel:

```
foo: &foo
  color: red

bar:
  <<: *foo
  name: qux
```

Is there any way to tell ruamel to preserve the position of the merge key within this block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the tweaking of two lines in the representer for mappings this
can be fixed, the positional information for the merge key was there,
it was just not used. Unfortunately that is a rather large function that
requires a few imports:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

if ruamel.yaml.version_info < (0, 15, 86):
    from ruamel.yaml.nodes import MappingNode, ScalarNode
    from ruamel.yaml.comments import comment_attrib, merge_attrib

    def represent_mapping(self, tag, mapping, flow_style=None):
        value = []
        try:
            flow_style = mapping.fa.flow_style(flow_style)
        except AttributeError:
            flow_style = flow_style
        try:
            anchor = mapping.yaml_anchor()
        except AttributeError:
            anchor = None
        node = MappingNode(tag, value, flow_style=flow_style, anchor=anchor)
        if self.alias_key is not None:
            self.represented_objects[self.alias_key] = node
        best_style = True
        # no sorting! !!
        try:
            comment = getattr(mapping, comment_attrib)
            node.comment = comment.comment
            if node.comment and node.comment[1]:
                for ct in node.comment[1]:
                    ct.reset()
            item_comments = comment.items
            for v in item_comments.values():
                if v and v[1]:
                    for ct in v[1]:
                        ct.reset()
            try:
                node.comment.append(comment.end)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        except AttributeError:
            item_comments = {}
        merge_list = [m[1] for m in getattr(mapping, merge_attrib, [])]
        merge_pos = getattr(mapping, merge_attrib, [[0]])[0][0]          # <<<<<<<< line added
        item_count = 0
        if bool(merge_list):
            items = mapping.non_merged_items()
        else:
            items = mapping.items()
        for item_key, item_value in items:
            item_count += 1
            node_key = self.represent_key(item_key)
            node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
            item_comment = item_comments.get(item_key)
            if item_comment:
                assert getattr(node_key, 'comment', None) is None
                node_key.comment = item_comment[:2]
                nvc = getattr(node_value, 'comment', None)
                if nvc is not None:  # end comment already there
                    nvc[0] = item_comment[2]
                    nvc[1] = item_comment[3]
                else:
                    node_value.comment = item_comment[2:]
            if not (isinstance(node_key, ScalarNode) and not node_key.style):
                best_style = False
            if not (isinstance(node_value, ScalarNode) and not node_value.style):
                best_style = False
            value.append((node_key, node_value))
        if flow_style is None:
            if ((item_count != 0) or bool(merge_list)) and self.default_flow_style is not None:
                node.flow_style = self.default_flow_style
            else:
                node.flow_style = best_style
        if bool(merge_list):
            # because of the call to represent_data here, the anchors
            # are marked as being used and thereby created
            if len(merge_list) == 1:
                arg = self.represent_data(merge_list[0])
            else:
                arg = self.represent_data(merge_list)
                arg.flow_style = True
            value.insert(merge_pos, (ScalarNode(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:merge', '<<'), arg))   # <<<<< line changed
        return node

    ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter.represent_mapping = represent_mapping



yaml_str = """\
foo: &foo
  color: red

bar:
  name: qux
  <<: *foo
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
foo: &foo
  color: red

bar:
  name: qux
  <<: *foo
```

The above tries to keep the absolute position, without taking deletion
or inserts of key-value pairs into account.

The above will not patch anything when using the next release of
`ruamel.yaml`, which will include these changes.

Comment: This totally works, thank you! Looking forward to the next release.

Comment: I pushed that version out yesterday. I do hope you realise that the position of the merge key doesn't influence the content of the mapping loaded, and that this just helps to keep the diff smaller of a round-trip smaller.

Comment: Yup, totally. This is just about keeping the diff small for me. Thanks!